# Arc-Sine equation to solve backwards for x rarely produces answer with 2*pi*n

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

This is most definitely a misunderstanding of the trigonometric side of this issue: I have created a short program that is supposed to first solve for Y with A, B, C and X in a sine function (a, b, and c are transformations for the sin function). I then have arc-sine being used to solve for X and compare the values between ranges for 2*pi*n to use. Am I missing something as to why this rarely produces results with the arc-sine equation that matches my generated X value?

```
import math
import random

while True:
    arcsin_all = []
    while True:
        a = round(random.uniform(-2*math.pi, 2*math.pi), 2)
        b = round(random.uniform(-2*math.pi, 2*math.pi), 2)
        c = round(random.uniform(-2*math.pi, 2*math.pi), 2)
        x = round(random.uniform(-2*math.pi, 2*math.pi), 2)
        if a == 0 or b == 0:
            print("Denominator(s) Zero")
            pass
        else:
            break
    print("A =",a,", B =",b,", C =",c,", X =",x)
    sin = round(a*math.sin(b*x+c), 2)
    print("Y =",sin)
    for n in range(-10, 10):
        arcsin = round((math.asin(sin/a)-c+2*(math.pi)*n)/b, 2)
        arcsin_all.append(arcsin)
    if x in arcsin_all:
        print("Solved")
    else:
        print("Not Solved")
    input("Again?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution of `Sin(u)=t` contains two series (due to the symmetry against vertical axis)

```
 u = arcsin(t) + 2*Pi*k
 u = Pi - arcsin(t) + 2*Pi*n
```

So you should form a list of possible soultions with both branches:

```
for n in range(-5, 5):
    arcsin = round((math.asin(sin/a)-c+2*(math.pi)*n)/b, 2)
    arcsin_all.append(arcsin)
    arcsin = round(((math.pi) - math.asin(sin/a) - c+ 2*(math.pi)*n)/b, 2)
    arcsin_all.append(arcsin)
```

Moreover, your rounding causes numerical errors - they are revealed often if you print arcsin_all list. For example, here 4.92 <> 4.93, so you must choose another checking method - compare values with some absolute tolerance (epsylon)

```
A = -4.93 , B = 0.09 , C = -0.22 , X = 4.93
Y = -1.09
[-344.14, -314.19, -274.33, -244.38, -204.52, -174.57, -134.7, -104.75, -64.89, -34.94, 4.92, 34.87, 74.73, 104.69, 144.55, 174.5, 214.36, 244.31, 284.17, 314.13]
Not Solved
```